# Post xml input file/data for Curl in webapi controller

Tags: xml, curl, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

We are trying to post data to mvc controller through CURL. The syntax we have build for this purpose is: 
curl -X POST -v -H 'Content-type: text/xml' -H "Connection:Keep-Alive" -H "Accept:application/html" -d @D:/RevoluzaSample.xml http://localhost:58532/api/Requisition/. 
The error we are getting is data passed to the controller is null.
The xml data is :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfRequisition>
<Requisition>
    <FarmUnit>farm1</FarmUnit>
    <CreatedDate>2012-02-22</CreatedDate>
  <DeliveryAddress >
   <Name>Test Address 1</Name>
   <AddrLine1>Sense and Sensibility</AddrLine1>
   <AddrLine2>ERTF</AddrLine2>
   <AddrLine2>SADAS</AddrLine2>
   <AddrLine2>RFFDE</AddrLine2>
   <AddrLine3>HGF</AddrLine3>
      <AddrLine4>HTF</AddrLine4>
 </DeliveryAddress> 
<RequisitionEntries>
   <ItemID>1</ItemID>
       <Quantity>19.95</Quantity>
</RequisitionEntries>
</Requisition>
<Requisition>
    <FarmUnit>farm1</FarmUnit>
    <CreatedDate>2012-02-22</CreatedDate>
  <DeliveryAddress >
   <Name>Test Address 1</Name>
   <AddrLine1>Sense and Sensibility</AddrLine1>
   <AddrLine2>ERTF</AddrLine2>
   <AddrLine2>SADAS</AddrLine2>
   <AddrLine2>RFFDE</AddrLine2>
   <AddrLine3>HGF</AddrLine3>
      <AddrLine4>HTF</AddrLine4>
 </DeliveryAddress> 
<RequisitionEntries>
   <ItemID>1</ItemID>
       <Quantity>19.95</Quantity>
</RequisitionEntries>
</Requisition>
</ArrayOfRequisition>
```

Please tell the proper syntax for post to controller through curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a working client for this Web API, I mean a web application that succesfully invokes this action, you can get the cURL command easyly using Chrome's developer console. Take these steps:

- open your web application in Chrome
- press F12 to open the developer console, and choose the Network tab (on the top menu)
- take the necessary actions to invoke the Web API action from the application
- go back to the console Network tab, look for the request int he left pane, right click on it and choose "Copy as cURL"

Now your clipboard have the exact cURL command to exactly reproduce the working request, including the payload, headers, and any other options.